# What is the best approach for this nested android layout view

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

I'm trying to create the layout part of my app. I wanna know the best approach of going about this section.

[image]

I'm thinking of going with something like this, but i think its too much for just displaying three elements

[image]

Comment: Your implementation is pretty good. Please also check a recommendation below about a `ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common practice for displaying similar layout. If you want, you can replace all nested layout to ConstraintLayout. It can improve code extensibility, but it can slightly slow down the rendering speed of the UI. 
As a result, I think your current variant is the most optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, thats fine but for the ImageView you will also need to nest it inside a CardView

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/beach_bg_placeholder" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thank you the suggestion. whats the card view use for though?

Comment: It's used represent the information in a card manner with a drop shadow (elevation) and corner radius as in this context just to make the imageView with round corners